# Группировать данные по рамкам лет

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка

Запрос выводит возрастную группу пользователей от 1900 г ... 2007 г. 
Вывод происходит по годам. 
Нужно сделать чтобы была одновременно группировка по годам и в рамках определенных возрастных групп, до 12, 12 - 18, 18 - 21, 21+.
Схему надеюсь понятно обрисовал. Не суть какие рамки, мне нужно сделать главное группировку по рамкам лет.
Все почти работает, нужно лишь дополнить GROUP BY.
 **Пример из ВКонтакте**[image: Пример из ВКонтакте]

```
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `year`,
      SUM(`activation`) AS `active`
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') >= (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) 
AND DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') <= (YEAR(NOW()) - 8)
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y')
    ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y')
```

Выводимые данные по этому запросу. Дата рождения и сколько человек с этим возрастом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так в чём проблема, где php? я вижу только js? и не одного кода рендера ваших рамок не на php не на js не html.

Comment: уточните, вопрос по отрисовке графики по данным или по написанию запроса для сбора данных?

Comment: У меня все готово уже, лишь нужно вывести данные из базы по рамкам лет, скрин лишь как показатель того, о чем я говорю. Это из ВК. У меня примерно такой же график. GROUP BY нужно как то дополнить, но я не пойму как(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вот готовый код.**

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 13) AND (YEAR(NOW()))
    THEN ' до 13 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 18) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 14)
    THEN ' от 14 до 18 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 23) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 19)
    THEN ' от 19 до 23'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 28) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 24)
    THEN ' от 24 до 28 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 33) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 29)
    THEN ' от 29 до 33 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 45) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 34)
    THEN ' от 34 до 45'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 46)
    THEN ' от 46 '
END `date_rozdenie`,  SUM(`activation`) AS `active`
FROM `users` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 8)
GROUP BY  
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 13) AND (YEAR(NOW()))
    THEN ' до 13 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 18) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 14)
    THEN ' от 14 до 18 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 23) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 19)
    THEN ' от 19 до 23'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 28) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 24)
    THEN ' от 24 до 28 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 33) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 29)
    THEN ' от 29 до 33 '
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 45) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 34)
    THEN ' от 34 до 45'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y') BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) AND (YEAR(NOW()) - 46)
    THEN ' от 46 '
END
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_rozdenie`, '%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте группировку по [case](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html). Схема такая

CASE WHEN <дата рождения> BETWEEN ... AND ... THEN 'от 18 до 21' WHEN ...
и т.д.

Comment: Если Вам не сложно конечно, можете ли показать на моем коде? Был бы весьма благодарен, так бы понял что к чему.